# How can I open web page in default browser and pass Basic Authentication in background in Java?

Tags: java, basic-authentication

I have a Java desktop application, and I have to open some web page using default browser by click a button. I can do it like this:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```

But there is a requirement: web page has basic authentication and it must have been passed automatically, without typing login and password by user.

How can I do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "web page has basic authentication and it must have been passed automatically, without typing login and password by user"?

Comment: i understood it as "HTTP basic auth", causing the browser to show up a login screen..?

Comment: Grzegorz Górkiewicz, I mean that in regular case, when user opens URL in browser he would see a form and have to input login and password, and only after he inputs and press OK, web page would be opened. Requirement is - when user clicks a button in our desktop application, he goes to the same URL, but right web page must be shown immediatly, user mustn't see an authentication form (logging in must be in background).

Answer (score 0):

check out how to operate the Browser (the non-java application) from java [using Robots as described here](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2212401)

Answer (score 0):

How is your desktop app authenticating the user?
Do you have an authentication or session ID after the user logs in through your desktop app?

If so, you need to add that to the URI and have a service end-point that knows how to deal with it. Not ideal as you are exposing the authentication ID as part of the URL.

For example

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse("https://myservice/loginFromDesktop?auth=" + URLEncoder.encoder(authID, "UTF-8");
```

This assumes you actually have control over the web service :)

Comment: There is no connection between desktop app auth and auth in web page - page belongs to the external system. Login and password for basic auth is the same for any user that has access to the button. If I add authID in URL string, may it have any conflicts with other request parameters? I already have 2 parameters, so can I just add an authID, and it will redirect me to the right page?

Comment: if you have no access to the external system, things are getting quite a bit more complicated. Does it have to be the standard browser?